# Clarification about some scalability terminology

Tags: scalability, plasma, sharding, terminology

I am currently reading about the scalability of Ethereum but I cannot really understand the difference between some terms that occur often.

What is the relation between the terms:

- Layer 1
- Layer 2
- on-chain
- off-chain
- Plama
- Sharding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to quote [this very good article about Ethereum scalability](https://medium.com/coinmonks/scaling-solutions-on-ethereum-explained-d970b66e28e5):

> At the moment we have in general two ways which might solve this
>   problem:
>
> 1. We build a blockchain where every node doesn’t have to process every
>      operation. → called Layer 1 solutions (or On-Chain solutions) e.g.
>      Sharding
> 2. we squeeze more useful operations out of Ethereum’s existing capacity
>      → called Layer 2 solutions (or Off-Chain solutions) e.g. State
>      Channels, Plasma
>
> Layer 1 solutions typically require a hard fork of the blockchain, on
>   the other hand Layer 2 solutions typically do not require a hard fork,
>   because they can be implemented as smart contracts.

So layer 1 means built-in functionalities while layer 2 means top level protocols.

On-chain operations are made inside the Ethereum network. Off-chain operations are made outside the network, and rely on the blockchain to ground their security.

Ethereum Plasma introduced a novel scaling solution that could enable Ethereum to reach many more transactions per second than currently possible. Like payment channels in the Bitcoin Lightning Network, Plasma is a technique for conducting off-chain transactions while relying on the underlying Ethereum blockchain to ground its security.

Essentially, sharding is a particular method for horizontally partitioning data within a database. More generally, the database is broken into little pieces called “shards”, that when aggregated together form the original database.

I hope this is helpful.